# pandas dataframe.resample() Silently Failing

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, syntax, dataframe

I have multiple dataframes that represent years worth of data that are sampling on average every 30 minutes. I am trying to graph the years worth of data and due to fluctuations with the observations/equipment, there are some anomalies that appear, making my graph appearing to be an area graph rather than a line graph. Obviously, this is not what I want. So, I tried to resample my dataframes by using df.resample('3W') and also df.resample('21D') to reduce the size down to only sample every three weeks. However, in both instances, the resample failed silently. Am I doing something wrong? Here is the code:

```
df1.resample('3W')
df2.resample('3W')
df4.resample('3W')
```

I also tried attaching `.mean()` onto the ends of each to no avail, just in case the default `how='mean'` was not kicking on.

to give you an example of my data, here is some:

```
      Temperature
time                            
2003-01-01 00:11:48         40.0
2003-01-01 00:11:48         40.0
2003-01-01 00:26:47         40.0
2003-01-01 00:26:47         40.0
2003-01-01 00:41:48         40.0
2003-01-01 00:41:48         40.0
2003-01-01 00:56:47         40.0
2003-01-01 00:56:47         40.0
2003-01-01 01:11:48         41.0
2003-01-01 01:11:48         41.0
2003-01-01 01:26:47         40.0
2003-01-01 01:26:47         40.0
2003-01-01 01:41:48         40.0
```

Again, they are all dataframes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you reassigning your DataFrames as the resampled versions? This is necessary because `resample` is not an inplace operation.  For example:

```
df1 = df1.resample('3W').mean()
```

Comment: Perfect. Thank you. I had mistaken `resample()` as such.